# BATCH File - Rename and Incremental folder number?

Tags: batch-file

I've hit a brick wall with a BAT file i'm trying to make.

This is my file structure..

c:\video\ `**`within this file I have various files/folders, some folders start `AB**` (THE `**`IS A FOUR DIGIT NUMBER) which I want to rename ARCHIVEAB`**` which I can do with this :-

```
for /D %%f in (C:\video\AB*) do rename "%%f" "ARCHIVE~%%~nxf"
```

My issue is that the video folder will always repopulate eventually with the same AB number, what I would like is if the AB number re-appeared would be for the file to have a number put in front of it sequentially - so I would end up with something like..

```
ARCHIVEAB1234
1ARCHIVEAB1234
```

and if another AB123 file appeared it would then become

```
ARCHIVEAB1234
1ARCHIVEAB1234
2ARCHIVEAB1234
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /D %%f in (.\AB1*) do (
 IF EXIST "ARCHIVE~%%~nxf" (
  SET reqren=Y
  FOR /l %%x IN (1,1,999) DO IF DEFINED reqren IF NOT EXIST "%%xARCHIVE~%%~nxf" (rename "%%f" "%%xARCHIVE~%%~nxf"&SET "reqren=")
 ) ELSE (rename "%%f" "ARCHIVE~%%~nxf")
)
GOTO :EOF
```

should see this problem off. You might want to change the `(1,1,999)` to `(100,1,999)` to preserve the directoryname-length consistency.