# Batch file for incremental renaming of files/folders with date

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I have a folder called `Output`. I want to rename that using a batch file to `Output_old05Aug15`, where `05Aug15` is today's date. However, if `Output_old05Aug15` is already present, then `Output` will be renamed as `Output_old05Aug15_2nd` and so on. All I need is a batch file that renames the folder accordingly.

EDIT:
Got to incrementally rename folders that already exist. Here's what I have done:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /D %%f in (.\Output) do (
 IF EXIST "Output_old*" (
  SET reqren=Y
  FOR /l %%x IN (2,1,999) DO IF DEFINED reqren IF NOT EXIST "Output_old_%%x" (rename "%%f" "Output_old_%%x"&SET "reqren=")
 ) ELSE (rename "%%f" "Output_old")
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I referred to this post [BATCH File - Rename and Incremental folder number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411637/batch-file-rename-and-incremental-folder-number)

Comment: What did you tried as code until now ?

Comment: @Hackoo, Edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem US locale, ie: 'Thu 08/06/2015'    
for /F "tokens=2 delims=/ " %%m in ("%date%") do set /A "n=(3*((1%%m)%%100-1))"
set month=JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec
set monthName=!month:~%n%,3!
set dt=%date:~7,2%%monthName%%date:~-2%

if exist Output (
  for /l %%x in (1,1,999) do (
    if %%x EQU 1 set new=Output_old%dt%
    if %%x GEQ 2 set new=Output_old%dt%v%%x
    if not exist !new! (
        echo !new!
        rename output !new!
        goto fin
    )
  )
)

:fin
```

I'll leave making proper ordinal indicators to you. Note that %date% format depends on locale so in case of US you will use `tokens=1 delims=/` in first `for`

Comment: whats your locale? can you post `echo %DATE%` output?

Comment: `echo %DATE%` gives `Thu 08/06/2015`. Locale set to US

Comment: I have adjusted the code for US locale and corrected one bug. See if it wokrs

Comment: Hi @rostok, I've come across an issue, It's always taking the first parameter of the date part i.e for `Thu 08/06/2015` and always renaming as `Output_old08Aug15`. This bold part is denoting the month. It should be like `Output_old06Aug15` considering the second parameter of the date part, i.e, `Thu 08/06/2015`. Considering the `%date%` as `Day mm/dd/yyyy`. Please help.

Comment: my bad, it should be `set dt=%date:~7,2%%monthName%%date:~-2%`